# Replacing は with って

Tags: particles, particle-は, particle-って

So I was talking to this girl, and she used the って in a rather odd way (at least one that I'm not acquainted with), I gave it some research and found out that って can replace は giving some kind of softer tone to the sentence.

Like 「マギーはかわいいね」 would become 「マギーってかわいいね」.

So the page where I found it was so vague, and it didn't clarify when to use it this way or anything.

So, could anyone help me with this one?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It's used to emphasize a word.

> アラビア[語]{ご}って、[難]{むずか}しくない？
>
> Arabiago tte, muzukashikunai?
>
> Arabic, you say? Isn't that difficult?

Or it's used as a type of verbal quotation marks used for direct quotes and indirect quotes:

> すぐ[来]{き}ますって。
>
> Sugu kimasu tte.
>
> He said he'd come soon.
>
> お[母]{かあ}さんに[聞]{き}いたら、「だめだ」って。
>
> Okāsan ni kiitara, "Dame da" tte.
>
> When I asked my mom, she said "no."

**Source:** https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6

Comment: hmmm i feel that both of your examples are quotation ones, I already know the って as the colloquial form of と for quotation, but I'm curious about the って replacing は as in the example I gave in the question. Do you know about this function of って?

Comment: nope, haven't heard of it then. Sorry couldn't be of more help. This must be where you got it from: http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/actionclause
According to this, it can be used casually to replace は to mark topic to form more casual slang topics. From the way that it sounds, as you mention it is vague, there probably is no formal way to use it, and it's often used in slang.

Comment: No worries, thank you for your help. I got it from here http://maggiesensei.com/2012/05/07/direct-indirect-speech-%EF%BC%86%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6tte/ they cover the quotation then they cover the other part. And I got this first when talking with a native, so it could be colloquial speech