# Can the word 新鮮 be used as an expression?

Tags: translation, meaning, expressions

I know the word 新鮮 means fresh and it is used as a na-adjective like for example a fresh salad (新鮮な野菜サラダ)

However I've recently seen it used in the following short sentence:

> あわててるリサさんって新鮮…！

It doesn't seem to be used as an adjective, so I'm confused about what it's​ doing here.

And here's some context:

> Group of friends are hanging out together
>   A: "リサ…you didn't invite me to the party…does this mean you hate me!?
>   B: "of course she hates you, how can anyone like a weirdo like you~!"
>   リサ: Tries to diffuse the situation and says  "No, no you've got it all wrong I don't hate you! Please there's a reasonable explanation as to why you didn't receive an invitation!"
>   C: takes a photograph of them with her camera and says - "あわててるリサさんって新鮮…！"

Is 新鮮 an expression of some sort then? Perhaps referring to how C just took a 'fresh' photo? Like how we say "hot off the press" in English? Or does it still retain the meaning of "fresh" and she's just omitting the noun that 新鮮 is describing?

Answer (score 2):

In plain Japanese it's 慌てているリサさんは新鮮だ (lit. "Flustrated Lisa is fresh.")。って works as an emphatic topic marker (see: [Replacing は with って](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/39667/5010)). This 新鮮 *is* a na-adjective (aka descriptive noun), and だ after 新鮮 is omitted (see: [what exactly is "体言止{たいげんど}め"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14524/5010) ). Here 新鮮 means something like "new (to me) and surprising."