# て　in place of は

Tags: particles

> ロンドン**て**どんな町かなと思っていたんです。

Why is て, not は, used in the sentence? This looks like a place for the topic marker…

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/39667/5010

Comment: Are you sure it’s て and not って ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This て is a shortened form of って, which can replace は in informal speech.

- [Difference between って and は as topic marker](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15004/5010)
- [Replacing は with って](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/39667/5010)

ロンドン**て**どんな町かなと思っていたんです。(colloquial)
= ロンドン**って**どんな町かなと思っていたんです。(colloquial)
= ロンドン**(と)は**どんな町かなと思っていたんです。